# How to Display Bootstrap Navigation Dropdown Items when User is in a Role?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created my Bootstrap navigation menus as follows:

```
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Processing Solutions", "Processing", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Industries Supported", "Industries", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Become A Partner", "Partner", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                @if(User.IsInRole("Admin")){
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                       aria-expanded="false">Admin<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Manage Users","Index","UserAdmin")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Manage Roles","Index","RolesAdmin")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Manage Groups","Index","GroupsAdmin")</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                }
                @if (User.IsInAnyRoles("Admin", "SalesAgent"))
                {
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sales Agents", "Index", "SalesAgents")</li>
                }
                @if (User.IsInAnyRoles("Admin", "Referral Agent"))
                {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Referral Agents", "Index", "ReferralAgents")</li>
                }
                @if (User.IsInAnyRoles("Admin", "Merchant"))
                {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Merchants", "Index", "Merchants")</li>
                }
                @if(User.IsInAnyRoles("Admin","Referral Agent","Sales Agent"))
                {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Leads", "Index","Leads")</li>
                }
            </ul>
```

Note that the Admin dropdown is only available to logged in users assigned to the Admin role.  I'm using an extension class to do this and works for all other navigation items except for this one.  In this case, when clicking on the dropdown caret / arrow, the submenu does not display.  How should I modify the above code to ensure the dropdown fires when Admin users are logged in?

Comment: Does it work if you exclude the check? (i.e. so anyone can see it)

Comment: @AmyBarrett Yes.  I also made separate menu items and the authorization system works as designed.